# About php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i need a simple suggestion on how to fix my problem.

There my function php:

```
$userID = $_GET['user'];
$code = $_GET['code'];

if (empty($code) || empty($userID)){
    die(error('Fill in all fields'));
}
```

I need the right code to put $code if it isnt right/true, i want the error: Code does not exist

(Sorry for my bad enlish but isnt my nature language)

I already tried that way too:

```
if (!my_function()) {
    // function returned a false value
 }
```

but it isn't fixing my issue, because when i put into my input box the "giftcode" ($code) generated by me, it says the error of: `!my_function`
So it isnt, fixing my issue.

Comment: What exact you want or describe more in question so this will help full for your problem.

Comment: Check here i posted the full question please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739239/about-php-and-mysql-tables

Comment: Does `my_function()` return something? What value(s) are you checking `$code` against? This example is not complete so it is challenging to help you. Please edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About php and mysql tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739239/about-php-and-mysql-tables)

Comment: Check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739239/about-php-and-mysql-tables

So you can help me dude

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.. Please come up with more detail and error message

> I need the right code to put $code if it isnt right/true, i want the
>   error: Code does not exist

To avoid this error, you can use isset function..
PHP isset() function check either the variable available or not...
You can simply try

```
if(isset($_GET['code']) && isset($_GET['user']) ){
  if (empty($_GET['code']) || empty($$_GET['user'])){
    die(error('Fill in all fields'));
}
```

**Updated:**

> I need to check if a value exists in a MySQL database table, please
>   help me if you can, i need a simple code to prevent someone trying to
>   redeem fake giftcodes in my site thats why i want a code to check if a
>   value exists in mysql db table

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
  $code = $_GET['code'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM giftTable WHERE code = $code;
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
     //do action
  } else{
     // else action

  }
}
```

Comment: I need to check if a value exists in a MySQL database table, please help me if you can, i need a simple code to prevent someone trying to redeem fake giftcodes in my site thats why i want a code to check if a value exists in mysql db table.

Comment: Can you contact me somewhere like Discord?

Comment: Here you can find my database schema screenshot: https://gyazo.com/5ab819e187a7c4da124067e315e359a9